# Can I make opengl extension pointers global?

Tags: c++, opengl

Using opengl/windows 10/visual c++ 2015

I have a 'Window' class in my program which creates and maintains a win32 screen window including making a 'modern' opengl context on it. As part of doing this it obtains pointers to lots of opengl 'extension' functions.

My question is can I store those extension pointers globally/class static or do I need to keep a copy for every instance or Window as they'll have different opengl contexts? Are the pointers valid and the same for every opengl context I create or do I need to do it over and over again for every window I create?

Comment: why are you manually loading gl extensions ?

Comment: @ampawd: Because GL extensions must be loaded manually. Either with an extension loader, or by doing all the legwork yourself.

Comment: @datenwolf yeah they must be loaded, I mean doing this manually is a wasting a time, if it is a client application that just uses gl API then it does matter to load extensions with `glew` or any other loader.

Comment: Actually, how does glew handle this?
From a quick look at it, it seems to have no means to support bindings to functions to multiple contexts, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Are the pointers valid and the same for every opengl context I create or do I need to do it over and over again for every window I create?

That depends on the operating system and the windowing system used. The [WGL specification says](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd374386%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), that OpenGL extension function pointers are permitted to be different for each OpenGL context:

> `wglGetProcAddress()`:
>
> ...
>
> **Remarks**
>
> The OpenGL library supports multiple implementations of its functions.
>   Extension functions supported in one rendering context are not
>   necessarily available in a separate rendering context. Thus, for a
>   given rendering context in an application, use the function addresses
>   returned by the wglGetProcAddress function only.

In contrast to that [X11/GLX specifies (page 35, section 3.3.12)](https://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/glx1.4.pdf) that OpenGL extension function pointers are invariant (i.e. don't change) regardless of the context:

> GL function pointers returned by `glXGetProcAddress` are independent of the currently bound context and may be used by any context which supports the extension.

In case of Windows the most viable approach would be to have a map between context handle and a structure holding all the function pointers, i.e.

```
struct glfunctions {
    /* all the function pointers */
};
std::map<HGLRC,glfunctions> context_glfunctions;
```

Feel free to add some form of LRU to the map, so that repeated lookups of the context don't have to go through the whole map.

Answer (score -1):

I can't understand why you think that copying pointers will make any different ? It does not matter, because of the pointer nature, if you copy them you will get several different pointers pointing to the same function - they won't point to another function thus you can store them ether globally or as a static member in a class. no matter

Comment: Actually in the case of OpenGL *it does* matter: The function pointers may not alter when copying, but different OpenGL contexts are allowed to give *different* pointers for functions of the *same* name!

Comment: @datenwolf what you mean pointers may not alter when copying ?

Comment: What I mean is that `void (*a)() = x; void (*b)() = a;` then `a == b && a == x && b == x`. However `wglMakeCurrent(dc, gl_a); a = wglGetProcAddress("glBindBuffer"); wglMakeCurrent(dc, gl_b); b = wglGetProcAddress("glBindBuffer");` then `a` and `b`may legally be different.