# Glew and multiple opengl contexts (Does it work?)

Tags: opengl

As a followup to [Can I make opengl extension pointers global?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38803133/can-i-make-opengl-extension-pointers-global/38803514#38803514) where I asked about making opengl function pointers global variables.

It was pointed out to me that on windows the function pointers are only valid for one single opengl context. I decided that I'd simply use a loader library to do it for me.

I've looked at the implementation in [glew](http://glew.sourceforge.net/) and [gl3w](https://github.com/skaslev/gl3w) which are both recommended on the opengl website, and both of those seem to simply dump the function pointers into global variables and so won't work if you have more than one window / opengl context in the process.

Am I missing something here, or can these libraries simply not be used if there is the possibility of more than one window using opengl in a process?

Comment: Use GLEW MX. Tutorial on using it along with GLFW: https://blog.gvnott.com/2013/05/18/tutorial-multiple-windows-with-glfw3-and-glew-mx/

Comment: @Mars: They discontinued MX [last month in GLEW 2.0.0](http://glew.sourceforge.net/log.html).

Comment: Two windows / contexts aren't necessarily two different implementations. If they're running on the same hardware it's very likely the procedures for the extensions go to the same place. If you're really concerned about this you can dedicate one thread to each context and then use Thread Local Storage to store the function pointers, that's actually effectively how WGL contexts work anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Those libraries are not guaranteed to work with multiple contexts.

That doesn't mean they *won't.* Merely that they don't do what is necessary to ensure that it functions in multiple contexts.

They would generally fail if the two contexts don't talk to the same OpenGL implementation. For example, if you got the Intel embedded GPU with one context and a discrete graphics card in the other. However, the OpenGL ICD driver model makes that somewhat unlikely (though not impossible).